# Text from DB is being trimmed

Tags: php, mysqli

I am programming a simple website with three pages. For each page I have a table in the DB with colunms containing the information to display on these pages. Almost like a blog where each row may be a blog post.

For example, in my DB (as VARCHAR) I might have the text:

> This is line 1 
>  This is line 2 
>  This is line 3

But when I select the data, get the rows and echo it, the text is somehow trimmed:

> This is line 1 This is line 2 This is line 3

The text is correctly formatted when I look at the fields in the DB, but it is displayed wrong on the website.

```
require('.connection.php');

if(isset($_GET['menyValg'])){
    $menyValg = $_GET['menyValg'];

    switch($menyValg){
        case "Hovedside":
            $sql = "SELECT tittel, tekst FROM hovedside";
            break;
        case "Tjenester":
            $sql = "SELECT tittel, tekst FROM tjenester";
            break;
        case "Kontakt":
            $sql = "SELECT tittel, tekst FROM kontakt";
            break;
        default:
            $sql = "SELECT tittel, tekst FROM hovedside";
    }
}else{
    $sql = "SELECT tittel, tekst FROM hovedside";
}

$result = $connection->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<h2 class='contentTittel'>".$row['tittel']."</h2><p class='contentP'>".$row['tekst']."</p><br>";
    }
}else{
    //could not find any data
}
```

Comment: HTML doesn't recognize newlines, try wrapping your output in `nl2br($row['tekst']);`, which converts a newline to a `<br />` tag.

Comment: what do you mean by correctly formatted - containing newline characters?  Newlines don't actually render as newlines on websites.

Comment: @Tolios Very nice, it worked. Made a variable '$text = nl2br($row['tekst']);' and echoed the variable instead. Thank you!

Comment: @saltcracker Happy to have helped, fellow Viking! ;-) Posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newline in your database is in fact printed as a newline (if you inspect the source), but HTML doesn't recognize newlines when printing data - to do that you'll need to convert all the newlines to `<br />` tags.

The simplest way of doing that is with the `nl2br()` function, like this.

```
echo "<h2 class='contentTittel'>".$row['tittel']."</h2><p class='contentP'>".nl2br($row['tekst'])."</p><br>";
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Thank you. Accepted as answer since you were the first one to comment it. I had to store it in a variable though, and then use it in the while-loop. If not, I would only receive a error 500.

Comment: Like: (*while loop thing*){ $text = $row['tittel']; then *echo thingy with $text*}. Eyy, vikings ftw! :)

Comment: You should have been able to concat it into the string, like shown in this answer. Just remember the closing parenthesis and dots to separate the string ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using two methods, the first one is using `nl2br` which converts new line characters into `<br />`

```
echo nl2br($row['tekst']);
```

or you can echo the text inside `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, nl2br worked if I made it into a variable and used that. 1+ for contributing.